# How to align an image using for loops in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a spaceship using for loops in python but the image isn't aligning when I output the code. Its coming up side by side instead of in top of each other. Any help is appreciated!

```
def print_box(size):

top_row = ""
for star in range(size - 0):
    top_row = top_row + "|"
print(top_row)


for row in range(size - 0):
    inner_row = "/"

    for space in range(size - 0):

        inner_row = inner_row + "\\"
    print(inner_row)


top_row = ""
for star in range(size):
        top_row = top_row + "|###| "
        top_row = top_row + "|   | "
        top_row = top_row + "|###| "
        top_row = top_row +"/| | |\  "
     top_row = top_row + "|----|----|"
print(top_row)
def main():

print_box(1)
print_box(1)
main()
```

Comment: You aren't adding any newlines, in your for loops, the lines should look more like: `top_row = top_row + "|###|\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Below is corrected code:

```
def print_box(size):
  top_row = ""
  for star in range(size - 0):
    top_row = top_row + "     |"
  print(top_row)
  for row in range(size - 0):
    inner_row = "    /"
    for space in range(size - 0):
      inner_row = inner_row + " \\"
    print(inner_row)
  top_row = ""
  for star in range(size):
    top_row = top_row + "   |###| \n"
    top_row = top_row + "   |   | \n"
    top_row = top_row + "   |###| \n"
    top_row = top_row +"  /| | |\  \n"
    top_row = top_row + "|----|----|\n"
  print(top_row)

def main():
  print_box(1)
  print_box(1)

main()
```